# Return php files as plain text except index

Tags: php, apache

I was wondering, is there a way I can block the execution of other php files on my server except the `index.php` in the root folder, which I redirect all calls to with this file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,NS]
```

I have no clue what those `-d`, `-f`, `-l` do individually, all I know is that they allow files like images and stuff to be returned instead of rewriting the address to `index.php` as well. Bad thing is that they allow addresses like `site.com/somescript.php` to be executed as well.

I was wondering if it is possible to disable the execution of any other php file within the root folder, but not make it inaccessible, i.e. return it as plain text?

Comment: The -d/-f/-l says "if the requested thing is not an existing directory, an existing file, or an existing symlink, then serve index.php in its place."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another rewrite rule that forbids any requests ending in `.php` except for `/index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=403,L,NC]
```

Alternatively if you would like to serve the other `.php` files as plain text:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    RemoveHandler .php
    php_flag engine off
</FilesMatch>
<Files index.php>
    AddHandler php5-script .php
    php_flag engine on
</Files>
```

Comment: That is ultimately what I would have to do, but I was hoping I could return the file as plain text instead of denying access to it?

Comment: @php_nub_qq added a new solution that should work the way you want. Ideally you'd move any sensitive PHP files out of the public directory!

Answer (score 0):

Typical solution for this issue is to move all your PHP code (except for the index.php) outside the DOCUMENT_ROOT dirrectory, so that Apache can not see them. For example, you now have:

```
/path/to/site.com
    index.php
    other1.php
    other2.php
```

Ideally, you want something like:

```
/path/to/site.com/public
    index.php

/path/to/site.com/lib
    other1.php
    other2.php
```

Then in your Apache config, you point to /path/to/site.com/public instead of /path/to/site.com. This way, your library files are invisible to Apache and can not be requested directly. Note, this will likely require some code changes because now your includes have moved, but this can likely be done simply by changing your include_path.

Comment: Yes this is what I have. But I want to explicitly forbid execution of other php scripts in the public directory, despite the fact I don't have any.